# Dialog dismiss delay - Android

Tags: android, dialog

I have a dialog and I want it to be dismissible on-touch-outside after a time delay.

If I do this -

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

And add a touch listener to an underlying view,

```
 listview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 500);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

obviously it won't work, since I've made it un-cancelable.

But if I do this -

```
 dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

I can't control the delay in dismissal.

Any window properties etc. I can use to control this? How can I track the outside-dialog-touch event?

Comment: idk why you would want that coz it might be a bad UX.. well you can use translucent activity instead of dialog and handle all the touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `Dialog` overriding `onTouchEvent`

```
private class MyDialog extends Dialog{

        // constructors

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            Rect dialogRect = new Rect();
            getWindow().getDecorView().getHitRect(dialogRect);

            if (!dialogRect.contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.cancel();
            }

            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Then you should "manually" create your `Dialog`:

```
 MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(this);
 myDialog.setTitle("Dialog Title");
 myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
 myDialog.show();
```